[ERROR]: Failed to execute goal org.yamcs:yamcs-maven-plugin:1.3.2:protoc (default) on project yamcs-api:
I am installing yamcs in windows 11, and unfortunately the project failed to build. I tried to see how I could resolve though it's still challenging... any ideas on how to resolve this. Below is the short output of the error message.
I did try to see how I can change the version of protoc plugin from 1.3.2, but I could not be able to find the file. So, if that might help, how can I find such file.
But also I tried to run mvn -fix -rf :yamcs-api hoping it could have helped, but still no.
So, what else can I do? Thanks in advance.

Please provide what you ran to to try install it and the full error message.
